# If $f'(x_0) = -2$, then find $\lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{f\left(x_0 - \frac{1}{2}k\right) - f(x_0)}{k}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can you explain the answer, step by step, for someone completely new to calculus?

> $$f'(x_0) = -2$$
>
> $$\lim \limits_{k \to 0} \frac{f\left(x_0 - \frac{1}{2}k\right) - f(x_0)}{k} = \text{?}$$

We believe the answer the professor is looking for is an integer, but not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your definition for the derivative is:

$ f'(x_0) = \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h} $

How is this different from what you have? What takes the place of $h$ in the limit that you were given?

Answer (score 0):

More hint: Let $h=-k/2$. Since $k\to 0$, $h\to 0$ as well.

Applying this variable substitution will give what you need, an integer.

Comment: That's a good tip. My wife is confused on how to evaluate what the two $f(x_0)$ expressions on top, and what information f'(x_0)= - 2 gives. For context, the professor gave the class this problem to solve before actually teaching about derivatives and such. And I don't have a good enough memory to coach her through it.